# How does append period work and why should I bother about it?

Tags: backup, backupexec

I'm sitting and trying to understand how `Appending Period` and more importantly WHY should I use it and HOW do I use it for smart and efficient backups.

I've been rummaging through tutorials, checking videos and looking at `Symantec` but I still don't get it. I know the basics of it. Append period counts from first data written and Overwrite period from when last data was written.

What I haven't been able to understand is

- Can OPP and AP ever clash with each other and mess up a scheme?
- When the AP has ended, does that mean that you can't ever add more data to that media unless you scratch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Append Period (APP) and the Overwrite Protection Period (OPP) perform two different tasks.

APP defines how long you are prepared to allow appending more jobs to a piece of media once you've started writing to it. It's analogous to asking, "For what time period am I prepared to allow backup sets to be written to the same piece of media"? Setting too long a time period may increase the risk in the event of the media failing. Setting too short a period may result in using too many media. APP is measured from when the media is allocated.

OPP defines for how long you want any backup set written to the media to be protected from overwriting. It's analogous to asking, "If I have a backup set, what's the minimum amount of time I want it to remain available"? Setting too short a time period may result in a backup set being overwritten before there is another, more recent, backup of that backup set. Setting too long a time period may result in you using too many media. OPP is measured from when the last backup set was written to the media.

The OPP and APP are reliant on your Media Protection settings being set to Full or Partial.

As an example, suppose you are doing full backups to tape 5 nights per week. You may wish to set your APP to 23 hours (so you don't reuse the same tape for more than one night) and the OPP to 6 days (so you will end up keeping backups on tape for around a week once you've taken the APP in to account).

> - Can OPP and AP ever clash with each other and mess up a scheme?

They work together to create the media usage scheme. It's not understanding them that messes it up!

> - When the AP has ended, does that mean that you can't ever add more data to that media unless you scratch it?

It means that you can't append more data to the end of the backup set. It will become overwritable when the OPP expires, or if you move the media to the Scratch Media set.